# EF Core: Map Many to Many relationship without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to create a many to many relationship in entity Framework Core using Fluent API
Here is my first model:

`MyCalculationSelector.cs`

```
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
  public string UserString { get { return Name; } }

  private IList<CalculationType> _calculationTypes;
  public virtual IList<CalculationType> CalculationTypes
    {
       get { return _calculationTypes; }
       set { _calculationTypes = value; }
    }
```

And this is my second model:

`MyCalculationType.cs`

```
 public int SortOrder { get; set; }

 public string UserString
 {
    get { return Name; }
 }

 public int CalculationMethod { get; set; }
```

I remember that EF 6 could easily make the many to many relationship from Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyCalculationSelector>().HasMany(x => x.MyCalculationTypes).WithMany();
```

Can we something like this be achieved in ef core? as of today, Hasmany-Withmany implementation is not possible

Comment: EF Core documentation -> Relationships -> [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev just following the documentation but there is not much for many to many relationship without navigation property

Comment: I would suggest reading the whole [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) section. For instance, there are  common topics for [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1) or [Without navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1) etc.

Comment: I've already read the documentation a couple of times but there are several things that ef core still lacks compared to ef6 i'm seriously thinking about migrating to another technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the documentation and have come up with this answer, please, someone who knows more than me and will correct me if I am wrong.

I first created my join table:

`CalculationSelectorCalculationType.cs`

```
public class CalculationSelectorCalculationType
    {
        public int CalculationSelector_Id { get; set; }
        public CalculationSelector CalculationSelector { get; set; }

        public int CalculationType_Id { get; set; }
        public CalculationType CalculationType { get; set; }
    }
```

`CalculationSelector.cs`

```
public CalculationSelector()
   {
      _calculationTypes = new List<CalculationSelectorCalculationType>();
      FontSize = 30;
   }
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
public string UserString { get { return Name; } }

private IList<CalculationSelectorCalculationType> _calculationTypes;
public virtual IList<CalculationSelectorCalculationType> CalculationTypes
    {
       get { return _calculationTypes; }
       set { _calculationTypes = value; }
    }
```

`CalculationType.cs`

```
 public int SortOrder { get; set; }

 public string UserString
 {
    get { return Name; }
 }

 public int CalculationMethod { get; set; }
```

...and finally my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CalculationSelectorCalculationType>().HasKey(p => new { p.CalculationSelector_Id, p.CalculationType_Id });
modelBuilder.Entity<CalculationSelectorCalculationType>().HasOne(p => p.CalculationSelector).WithMany(x => x.CalculationTypes).HasForeignKey(p => p.CalculationSelector_Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<CalculationSelectorCalculationType>().HasOne(p => p.CalculationType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.CalculationType_Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can represent this with a private field or property:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyCalculationSelector>()
    .HasMany(x => x.MyCalculationTypes)
    .WithMany("NameOfThePrivateFieldOnMyCalculationType");
```

This way the navigation property is not exposed publically, but you can still use the Navigation Property on `MyCalculationSelector` without needing to traverse the intermediate join table.

Comment: In the EF Core docs, that is usually called a "shadow property"